# Как передавать несколько аргументов внутрь компонента React

Tags: reactjs

Не понимаю как в тег h1 передать className и name, в 4 строчке совсем не понятно, что именно нужно писать кроме name в компоненте 'Welcome'.

```
function Welcome(myClass, myName) {
  return <h1 className={myClass.name}>Привет, {myName.lastName}</h1>;
}
const element = <Welcome name="container" lastName="Алиса"/>;
ReactDOM.render(
  element,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Значение передается только в 'class', но имя пользователя так и не выводит. Вывод получается такой:
[image: Вот что отображается в работе приложения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

все данные которые вы передаете в компонент, попадают в один объект(пропсы).
Ваш компонент будет выглядеть вот так:

```
function Welcome(props) {
  return <h1 className={props.name}>Привет, {props.lastName}</h1>;
}
```